# O 'ionic' não é reconhecido como um comando interno

Tags: ionic

Estou tentando criar um app com o ionic mas acontece esse erro:

'ionic' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Você, tem certeza que está instalado o IONIC no seu computador? faz um teste por favor no CMD, ionic -v e veja a versão instada em seu computador.

Comment: é interessante informar sistema operacional para podermos ajudar

Comment: pela mensagem de erro deve ser windows. O mesmo está acontecendo comigo. Os comandos "node" e "npm" são reconhecidos, mas o ionic não.

Comment: Para instalar o Ionic e o Cordova, é recomendado a versão mais recente do node. Desinstale e reinstale-o para receber a versão atual. ;)

Answer (score 10):

Por algum motivo durante a instalação do npm não foi adicionado a variavel de ambiente.

Adicione dentro de Path:
C:\Users\meu.usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 2):

Verique se na sua maquina esta instalado a ultima versão do SDK do Java.
Sem ele o ionic não consegue criar as variáveis de ambiente no momento da instalação.

Feito a instalação do SDK, realize novamente a instalação do ionic.

npm install -g cordova ionic

Para testar a instalação.

ionic -v

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se você tem o Chocolatey instalado na sua maquina.
Na própria instalação do node há uma opção para fazer a instalação do mesmo!

Você pode encontrar mais em: https://chocolatey.org/